# Raspberry pi 2 Iot Core asp service stops in short time - pipeline exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, powershell, raspberry-pi2, dnx

I have a raspberry pi 2 model B. I went by [this](https://www.hackster.io/iddi/windows-10-iot-core-publish-asp-net-web-application-d9dcd4) tutorial, to deploy an asp.net mvc web application on it. First it looked like it works like charm.
After the application starts, I can make a few clicks, reload pages, the IO is read well.
However after a short period of time, the service stops, and won't answer requests anymore. If i send few requests rapidly, or I use two devices to connect to the port it stops instantly. When I restart the application in Powershell it works again for a short time. Stopping the service can result with two types of messages:

---

```
[192.168.0.34]: PS C:\PROGRAMS\DnxPi> .\web.cmd
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

The remote pipeline has been stopped.
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Management.Automation.Remoting.PSRemotingDataStructureException



[192.168.0.34]: PS C:\PROGRAMS\DnxPi> ^C
[192.168.0.34]: PS C:\PROGRAMS\DnxPi> .\web.cmd
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.

The pipeline has been stopped.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], PipelineStoppedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PipelineStopped

---
```

Can you help me out what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

If you hit refresh a few times the server will stop responding. There's an issue right now with the WebListener server when running on ARM that are yet to investigate.